# Keycloak failing to start with "failed to resolve interface private"

Tags: networking, docker

This is a note for my future self and anyone running into an failed to resolve interface error with Keycloak/Wildfly.

> MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.private: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.network.interface.private: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If docker uses ipv6 the wildfly server will fail with this error (at the time this bug was present in Keycloak 8.0.2).

One solution is to disable ipv6 for the docker container.

If you are using docker-compose:

```
  networks:
    kc_net:
      driver: bridge
      enable_ipv6: false
```

otherwise use the commandline flag.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:9.0.2 -Djboss.bind.address.private=127.0.0.1 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

It's the `docker run` command from https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker but with two additional options:

```
-Djboss.bind.address.private=127.0.0.1 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Running it like this bypasses the issue on podman and probably docker.

```
podman run --rm -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin registry.hub.docker.com/jboss/keycloak:latest -Djboss.bind.address.private=127.0.0.1 -Djboss.bind.address=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

with ipv6 enabled, you can use these JAVA_OPTS to make wildfly start

```
JAVA_OPTS = "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true -Djboss.bind.address.private=::1 -Djboss.bind.address=::"
```

Comment: This approach worked on my machine when using Keycloak 12.0.4, passing it with -e when launching the container

Comment: ...unfortunately I hit another error when I tried to invoke the internal scripts, but it set me on the right track for my case